# How to use ros2_control with actual hardware communicating via etherCAT?

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, hardware-interface, ros2-controllers, ethercat

I am learning ros2_control with the real hardware. I need some help writing hardware interface for the current setup. I do not have experience writing on the communication side of the real hardware.

setup:
I have Jetson nano, drives, motors, and sensors communicating via EtherCAT and using ros2 foxy and SOEM_ROS2 package. these were installed and running without ros2 control, simply via publisher and subscriber. The whole system controls the x,y,z axis with prismatic joint. It is not a robot. so no end effector.
Now, I want to integrate ros2 control with the whole system. I don't know how to get the values from the hardware for the read and write methods of the hardware interface.
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this [EtherCAT driver](https://github.com/ICube-Robotics/ethercat_driver_ros2)?

Comment: thank you for the  answer. I am trying at the moment with the existing packages on the system. In init method i am writing a subscriber and publisher to get the messages from the existing architecture. and I will write the read and write methods from the values that I receive. will see how that goes.!!!!

Comment: We don't suggest using a node inside the hardware component, that's what the ros2_controllers are for.

Comment: so I have to write the completely new hardware component ? or is there any other work around?

Comment: Have you checked the link above? E.g., [here](https://icube-robotics.github.io/ethercat_driver_ros2/user_guide/config_cia402_drive.html) you can see how to configure the EtherCAT plugin for a motor.
No need to write your own hardware component if you can use ethercat_driver_ros2

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. so I am using ros2 foxy, I will still have to check for compatibility.  but that's good starting point to look at. Thank you!!!

Comment: Anyways, I suggest to update to a ROS distribution which is not EOL already.